# Finding if there is a diffeomorphism which pushes forward one vector field to the other

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a pair of vector fields on a real line how can I see if there exists a diffeomorphism, which pushes forward one to the other? I have
$$ V_1 = 2sinx\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \enspace V_2 = sin^2x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \enspace V_3 = (2sinx+sin^2x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} . $$
If $y=F(x)$ is a diffeomorphism then the pushforward of $V_1$ will be 
$$ F^*(2sinx\frac{\partial}{\partial x}) = \frac{2sin(G(y))}{G'(y)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y},  $$ where $G(y) = F^{-1}(x)$. For $V_1$ to be pushed forward to $V_3$ I need
$$\frac{2sin(G(y))}{G'(y)} = 2siny+sin^2y.$$
I tried solving this differential equation, but it gave me nothing and I don't think it is the correct way to do it, any hints?